# upgrade redis 2.4.14 to redis 2.6.14, command "service redis start" always hangs

Tags: redis, upgrade

I installed redis2.4.14 before. 
Yestoday, I got redis2.6.14, and directly "cd redis-2.6.14/src ; make && make install".
and I removed dump.rdb and redis.log of redis-2.4.14.
I also upgraded the configuration file to 2.6.14.
I added redis to service when I installed redis-2.4.14.
I execute command "service redis start", but it always hangs with no "ok" information.

```
[tys@localhost bin]# service redis start
Starting redis-server:
```

I can use redis nomally

```
[tys@localhost redis]# redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set name tys
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get name
"tys"
```

but if I type "ctrl + c" or "ctrl + z", "redis-cli" will hang on.

when I reboot the system, linux boot process hangs on "Starting redis-server"
(Sorry, I am too "young" to post image. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/iQnlyAAWE9Y)

But I can ssh it.It's a virtual machine.
There is no error in the redis.log.

```
[1420] 11 Aug 04:27:05.879 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.14
[1420] 11 Aug 04:27:05.880 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
[1420] 11 Aug 04:27:05.903 * DB loaded from disk: 0.023 seconds
[1420] 11 Aug 04:27:05.903 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Here is my redis init.d script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#redis - this script starts and stops the redis-server daemon
#
# chkconfig:   235 90 10 
# description:  Redis is a persistent key-value database
# processname: redis-server
# config:      /etc/redis.conf
# config:      /etc/sysconfig/redis
# pidfile:     /var/run/redis.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

redis="/usr/local/bin/redis-server"
prog=$(basename $redis)

REDIS_CONF_FILE="/etc/redis.conf"

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/redis ] && . /etc/sysconfig/redis

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/redis

start() {
    [ -x $redis ] || exit 5
    [ -f $REDIS_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $redis $REDIS_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -QUIT
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

reload() {
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc $redis -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Comment: eh, how can I post large segment of code ?
evry line with 4 spaces ? 
Don't laugh at me, the above code costed me much spaces.

Comment: command "service redis stop" could be executed nomally. After stop command, "service redis start" will return "Starting redis-server: /bin/bash: line 1:  1420 Quit                    /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf
                                                           [FAILED]"  But the log file tells no failed informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resovled it with Josiah' help in the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-db.

It's "daemonize no" in my redis.conf. Redis started nomally, after I switched to "daemonize yes".